# Show disk usage per site of network

Tags: multisite

How do I add a new column in `/wp-admin/network/sites.php` to show the total disk usage ?

I found a very old post [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67876/how-to-check-disk-space-used-by-media-library/73333#73333), but I'm not sure it works fine with my 400+ sites network !

I'd also like to display the disk usage in the dashboard of every single site, so each client can see how much disk they are using.

Comment: did you try the answer found there? If it doesn't work for you then it's extremely unlikely any answer you get here would work for you for the same reasons

Comment: to get some approximation stats on a regular Linux server, maybe run a cron job with relevant disk-usage Linux commands and pipe it to a file that WP can parse.